# scheduling various things and balancing bandwidth while using torrent and uploading

Tags: windows-7, powershell, shell-script, bittorrent, bandwidth

I have approximately 200 files to be downloaded via BitTorrent,
 these files can be from 200mb to 4.8 GB

on the same time I want to take backup of some already existing pdfs in my home directory,
the pdfs are approximately 10 GB (total all), I will use Google drive to take backup

I want to know is there a script or any programm available with which I can schedule 
the download and upload simultaenously that when I am not downloading the upload starts and when I am downloading the upload is not happening and the time slots (decided by me) are the ones in which my torrent client is downloading files.(The time when I sleep) rest of the day it does keep downloading but with a limited bandwidth, what happens currently is I have to manually keep track of such things i.e. which file uploaded which one downloaded and when to pause restart or schedule, and it has become very difficult for me to keep a track of this heavy data.
I take a copy paper and manually makes notes to track all this, is there an easy way out there may be if I need to write some code give me a hint as what exactly should I do, I have Windows 7 and Linux environment both on same machine and I have to frequently switch from Windows 7 to Linux and Linux to Windows 7 so each time manually starting upload/download becomes a tedious thing for me, if I forget my precious time gets wasted (which is exactly why I am posting here) also I want to control bandwidth so that while I am browsing the torrent client does not eats up much bandwitdh , the total bandwidth available to me
 is 30kbps.

Comment: uTorrent has a scheduler. Can't you use that and also schedule an upload script via Task Scheduler to run when uTorrent's paused/stopped?

Comment: I am not aware of any such option please help me to find it out where exactly is it located?

Comment: Which one - uTorrent's scheduler? Used to be under `Options / Preferences / Scheduler` last time I checked ([FAQ](http://www.utorrent.com/help/faq/network#faq6)).

Comment: oh thanks a lot for pointing out and what do I do to be able to automatically keep updating to my google drive?

Comment: See [here](http://tambnguyen.com/4248-how-i-use-google-drive-back-up-my-files/) for help scripting your uploads to Google Drive.